# Why does python ML code stop in the middle of the algorithm?

Tags: python, nlp, random-forest

I am running a ML algorithm using Python.

my dataset is large as it is based on NLP

the problem I am facing is that the algorithm stops running in the begining and i have no visibility of why it stopped and how to make it continue

Here is the out put that i got after 24 hours of running

```
Python 3.11.5 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Sep 11 2023, 13:26:23) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 8.15.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

runfile('D:/__Services/0500-SuggestDiagnoses/TrainModel.py', wdir='D:/__Services/0500-SuggestDiagnoses')
d:\__services\0500-suggestdiagnoses\trainmodel.py:44: UserWarning: pandas only supports SQLAlchemy connectable (engine/connection) or database string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connection. Other DBAPI2 objects are not tested. Please consider using SQLAlchemy.
  df_features = pd.read_sql("EXEC P500GetFeatures "+IsTraining + ", "+ Colums_Number_In_Training + ", " + Number_Of_Records , conn)
d:\__services\0500-suggestdiagnoses\trainmodel.py:45: UserWarning: pandas only supports SQLAlchemy connectable (engine/connection) or database string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connection. Other DBAPI2 objects are not tested. Please consider using SQLAlchemy.
  df_results = pd.read_sql("EXEC P500GetResults '" + Scheme + "'" , conn)
C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\multiclass.py:84: UserWarning: Label not 23 is present in all training examples.
  warnings.warn(
C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\multiclass.py:84: UserWarning: Label not 27 is present in all training examples.
  warnings.warn(
C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\multiclass.py:84: UserWarning: Label not 68 is present in all training examples.
  warnings.warn(
C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\multiclass.py:84: UserWarning: Label not 103 is present in all training examples.
  warnings.warn(
C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\multiclass.py:84: UserWarning: Label not 129 is present in all training examples.
  warnings.warn(
```

and here is my code

```
import pyodbc 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
import datetime
import winsound
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import pickle
import sys

Scheme = "ICD10AM" #sys.argv[1]
Colums_Number_In_Training = "10000" #sys.argv[2]
Number_Of_Records = "10000000" #sys.argv[3]
ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=MyServer;Database=MyDB;User Id=ABC;Password=***********;"


ParentFolder = "D:\\__Services\\0500-SuggestDiagnoses\\"

Model_File_Name = ParentFolder + "Model_"+Scheme+".pkl"
Binarizer_File_Name = ParentFolder + "Binarizer_"+Scheme+".pkl"


IsTraining = "1"



now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 300)

conn = pyodbc.connect(ConnectionString)

df_features = pd.read_sql("EXEC P500GetFeatures "+IsTraining + ", "+ Colums_Number_In_Training + ", " + Number_Of_Records , conn)
df_results = pd.read_sql("EXEC P500GetResults '" + Scheme + "'" , conn)

conn.commit()
conn.close()     #<--- Close the connection


df_features.shape
df_features = df_features.set_index(['PtsID','VisitID']).pivot(columns='CUI')['Frequency']
df_features[np.isnan(df_features)] = 0

df_results = df_results.groupby(['PtsID','VisitID'])[["Code"]].agg(list)#.reset_index()
df = pd.merge(df_features, df_results, on = ['PtsID','VisitID'])

multilabel_binarizer = MultiLabelBinarizer()
multilabel_binarizer.fit(df['Code'])
y = multilabel_binarizer.transform(df['Code'])

pickle.dump(multilabel_binarizer, open(Binarizer_File_Name, 'wb'))

X = df[df.columns.difference(["Code"])]
X.to_csv(ParentFolder + "Files\\" + "X_" + now + ".csv",  index=True)

xtrain, xval, ytrain, yval = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=9)
mdl = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000)
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(mdl)
clf.fit(xtrain, ytrain)
pickle.dump(clf, open(Model_File_Name, 'wb'))
```

datasets are

**Exec P500GetFeatures**

```
IsTraining  CUIsCount   RecordsCount    PtsID   VisitID CUI Frequency
1   10  99  3   145834  C0000726    6
1   10  99  3   145834  C0005767    13
1   10  99  3   145834  C0013227    24
1   10  99  3   145834  C0018935    12
1   10  99  3   145834  C0039225    9
1   10  99  3   145834  C0262926    9
1   10  99  3   145834  C0525032    4
1   10  99  3   145834  C0817096    10
1   10  99  4   185777  C0000726    2
1   10  99  4   185777  C0005767    11
1   10  99  4   185777  C0013227    21
1   10  99  4   185777  C0013404    21
1   10  99  4   185777  C0013604    8
1   10  99  4   185777  C0018935    4
1   10  99  4   185777  C0039225    6
1   10  99  4   185777  C0262926    6
1   10  99  4   185777  C0817096    12
1   10  99  6   107064  C0000726    2
1   10  99  6   107064  C0005767    4
1   10  99  6   107064  C0013227    12
1   10  99  6   107064  C0013604    8
1   10  99  6   107064  C0018935    20
1   10  99  6   107064  C0039225    3
1   10  99  6   107064  C0262926    7
1   10  99  6   107064  C0525032    8
1   10  99  9   150750  C0000726    2
1   10  99  9   150750  C0005767    6
1   10  99  9   150750  C0013227    9
1   10  99  9   150750  C0013604    12
1   10  99  9   150750  C0018935    4
1   10  99  9   150750  C0262926    8
1   10  99  9   150750  C0525032    4
1   10  99  9   150750  C0817096    4
1   10  99  10  184167  C0000726    2
1   10  99  10  184167  C0005767    2
1   10  99  10  184167  C0013227    3
1   10  99  10  184167  C0018935    4
1   10  99  10  184167  C0262926    1
1   10  99  11  194540  C0000726    2
1   10  99  11  194540  C0005767    3
1   10  99  11  194540  C0013227    18
1   10  99  11  194540  C0013604    32
1   10  99  11  194540  C0039225    63
1   10  99  11  194540  C0262926    6
1   10  99  11  194540  C0817096    6
1   10  99  12  112213  C0000726    6
1   10  99  12  112213  C0005767    2
1   10  99  12  112213  C0013227    9
1   10  99  12  112213  C0013604    4
1   10  99  12  112213  C0018935    8
1   10  99  12  112213  C0262926    4
1   10  99  12  112213  C0525032    4
1   10  99  12  112213  C0817096    2
1   10  99  13  143045  C0000726    2
1   10  99  13  143045  C0005767    2
1   10  99  13  143045  C0013227    6
1   10  99  13  143045  C0013404    7
1   10  99  13  143045  C0013604    8
1   10  99  13  143045  C0018935    4
1   10  99  13  143045  C0039225    3
1   10  99  13  143045  C0262926    4
1   10  99  13  143045  C0817096    14
1   10  99  17  161087  C0005767    6
1   10  99  17  161087  C0013227    9
1   10  99  17  161087  C0018935    4
1   10  99  17  161087  C0039225    54
1   10  99  17  161087  C0262926    5
1   10  99  17  161087  C0817096    6
1   10  99  17  194023  C0000726    2
1   10  99  17  194023  C0005767    6
1   10  99  17  194023  C0013227    9
1   10  99  17  194023  C0013604    4
1   10  99  17  194023  C0018935    8
1   10  99  17  194023  C0039225    27
1   10  99  17  194023  C0262926    7
1   10  99  18  188822  C0000726    2
1   10  99  18  188822  C0005767    9
1   10  99  18  188822  C0013227    45
1   10  99  18  188822  C0013404    7
1   10  99  18  188822  C0013604    4
1   10  99  18  188822  C0018935    8
1   10  99  18  188822  C0039225    72
1   10  99  18  188822  C0262926    15
1   10  99  18  188822  C0817096    2
1   10  99  19  109235  C0000726    2
1   10  99  19  109235  C0013227    9
1   10  99  19  109235  C0013604    4
1   10  99  19  109235  C0018935    4
1   10  99  19  109235  C0039225    48
1   10  99  19  109235  C0262926    5
1   10  99  19  109235  C0525032    4
1   10  99  19  109235  C0817096    2
1   10  99  20  157681  C0000726    8
1   10  99  20  157681  C0005767    1
1   10  99  20  157681  C0013227    15
1   10  99  20  157681  C0013404    7
1   10  99  20  157681  C0013604    4
1   10  99  20  157681  C0018935    4
1   10  99  20  157681  C0039225    6
```

**Exec P500GetResults**

```
69141   136542  39958   A02
46693   183574  17303   A02
65733   168926  23212   A02
83908   180356  37704   A02
27367   136441  4538    A02
44437   181557  44035   A02
5018    154356  57999   A03
84972   121388  59570   A03
5018    154356  58010   A03
6928    182382  51284   A03
9833    167211  19164   A03
5018    154356  12160   A03
12021   184622  6916    A03
44969   174918  42013   A04
14269   106979  4165    A04
```

the datasets contain large number of records (100k), so i will only share a sample of it

Comment: Test your algorithm on smaller case, 1% of your data or so. Debug your code, line by line, check if everything looks as expected.   Also, how many classes you have - how many models OneVsRestClassifier will contain?